# VirtualBox 5.x (32bit) & VirtualBox 6.x (64bit) installed side by side?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have Virtualbox 5.2 installed on my Windows** as I use it for some 32bit machines.  Can I also have VirtualBox 6.x installed separately as well (to use some exclusively 64bit machines)? Thank you very much.

** On an Intel based i5 with Virtualization support.

Comment: I don't think you can, but is there a reason you don't install VirtualBox 5.2 x64? you can still use x86 machines with that, but run x64 machines next to it.

Comment: @LPChip No particular reason. I just don't want to inadvertently mess up my existing 5.2 setup with all good working machines :D.  I just wanted to have 6.x (the future right?) to play with and slowly move to it step by step (considering my limitations). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You should be able to run 32-bit guests and 64-bit guests on Virtual Box 6.  Most virtualizers work this way. I would only have one version of Virtual Box installed.

Comment: I have used version 6 and had many issues with it, reverted back to 5.2. I would not try to migrate 5.2 to 6, so my solution would be, install the x64 version of 5.2. It should keep everything working but allow you to add x64 machines to the mix.

Comment: I do not understand clearly what do you asking for. With Virtualbox you can run x64 and x86 operation systems virtually. You do not need to use two versions of Virtualbox.

Comment: Consider a different virtulizing application. I use the newest version of VMware Workstation and run both 64-bit and 32-bit guests (as old as DOS 6)

Comment: @spcsLrg This may help you: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50977